# Getting error with a mixing using gulp-sass

Tags: gulp, compass, gulp-sass

I am attempting to use gulp-sass with my project, but when I run the gulp task I am continually getting the error:

"Error: file to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset"

My gulp file is very basic at the moment:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ compass: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

I am able to compile sass fine by using 'compass watch' in the terminal, but wanted to try to do it with gulp, but I am pretty stumped on this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 'watch' task set, so that's why your gulp file isn't doing anything -you didn't tell the gulp file anything other than what to run the sass function on, and where it should spit your CSS.

You need to set a watch function (so when the files change, something happens), then anything else you want to do (minify, expand, compact, reload your browser) and then wrap your sass and watch tasks that will get called in a default function when you run gulp from the terminal.

There's a lot of tutorials available, so you be able to find one that will help you. Although, I find that gulp really finnicky with your dev environments, and different gulp-sass modules that work differently (for instance gulp-ruby-sass doesn't seem to like globbing, so there's a lot of gotchas)

Here's just an example of my gulpfile, heads up though, this is currently throwing errors importing my variables folder in my sass.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('postercatalogue/sites/all/themes/postomega/sass/**/*.scss', {style:'expanded'})
    .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
    });
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
    });    
gulp.task('default',['styles','watch']);
```